# Why would this program output "java.io.BufferedReader@Number"?

Tags: java, csv

This is a quick one that stumps me. I've got a Java Program with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String file1 = args[0];
        String file2 = args[1];
        String output = args[2];

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output), "utf-8"));

        // Get the file
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

        ArrayList<String> masterRBT = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Read the files
        while(br1.readLine() != null) {
            masterRBT.add(br1.toString());
            System.out.println(br1.toString());
        }
```

Read the file (in this case, a .csv), and output it to the command line.

I use the command line to run the program, plus three parameters, using so (it only really uses the first one):

> java -jar csvdiff.jar mainfile.csv subfile.csv output.csv

But then, it returns this:

> java.io.BufferedReader@17dfafd1

Repeatedly, as if on loop. I tried putting in a Try/Catch error, but it still does the same - no errors. I've opened the .csv files, and verified its contents.

The CSV files are located in the same directory as the .jar file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are attempting to print an instance of `BufferedReader` not the data you are reading from it

Change

```
while(br1.readLine() != null) {
    masterRBT.add(br1.toString());
    System.out.println(br1.toString());
}
```

to

```
while((String line = br1.readLine()) != null) { 
    masterRBT.add(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: D'OH. I totally forgot that one. I feel so stupid. Truly, "the last place you look is the first place it was in, but didn't find in the first try." Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing out `br1.toString()` - you're calling `toString()` *on the `BufferedReader` itself*. `BufferedReader` doesn't override `toString()`, so you're getting the implementation from `Object`, as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--):

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

That's not what you want. Presumably you actually want to print out the line that you've just read - but you've thrown that away by now. You want:

```
String line;
while((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    masterRBT.add(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Or as a `for` loop:

```
for (String line = br1.readLine(); line != null; line = br1.readLine()) {
    masterRBT.add(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

As a general matter, if you start seeing `ClassName@Number` in output, that's almost *certainly* a similar problem of calling `toString()` on an object which doesn't override it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing the line but the reader itself, to print the line change your code like this:

```
    // Read the files
    String line;
    while((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        masterRBT.add(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
 String str;

     while((str=br1.readLine()) != null) {
                masterRBT.add(str);
                System.out.println(str);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because BufferedReader.toString() just returns the class name and hash value of the object.

Use BufferedReader.readLine() to get the String instead.